# Ruby Watir: Selecting a specific row

Tags: ruby, row, watir

Consider the following html
http://www.carbide-red.com/prog/test_table.html

I have worked out that I can move left to right on the columns using

```
browser.td(:text => "Equipment").parent.td(:index => "2").flash
```

to flash the 3rd column over on the line containing "Equipement"

But how can I move down a certain number of rows? I am having terrible luck using .tr & .rows, no matter how I try it just crashes out when using those. Even something as simple as

```
browser.tr(:text => "Equipment").flash
```

Am I just misunderstanding how tr/row works?

Comment: `browser.tr(:text => "Equipment").flash` does not work because there is no tr with that exact text. You need to do a regex instead `/Equipment/`.

Comment: Are you trying to go down a certain number of rows from the top or from a row containing a certain cell? Your examples reference the first row/cell, but its not clear if that is just an example or you are always moving in relation to that one cell.

Comment: I want to find a row containing a certain text element and then start moving down from there. Thanks for the regex hint, that worked and I like regex.  Can Ruby return regex matches like $1 $2 $3 in Perl?

Comment: I updated my answer to include some examples of getting rows after a specific row. And yes, Ruby can return regex matches (I believe it is the same as Perl but I have not programmed in Perl).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Specific Row/Column**

It sounds like you have already calculated which row/column you want. You can get the cell at a specific row/column index by simply doing:

```
browser.table[row_index][column_index]
```

Where `row_index` and `column_index` are integers for the row and column you want (note that it is zero-based index).

**Specific Row**

You can also do the following to select rows based on an index:

```
browser.table.tr(:index, 1).flash 
browser.table.row(:index, 2).flash
```

Note that `.tr` includes nested tables while `.row` ignores nested tables.

**Update - Find Rows After Specific Row**

To find a row after a specific row containing a certain text, determine the index of the specific row first. Then you can locate the other rows in relation to it. Here are some examples:

```
#Get the 3rd row down from the row containing the text 'Equipment'
starting_row_index = browser.table.rows.to_a.index{ |row| row.text =~ /Equipment/ }
offset = 3
row = browser.table.row(:index, starting_row_index + offset)
puts row.text
# => CAT03 ...

#Get the 3rd row down from the row containing a cell with yellow background colour
starting_row_index = browser.table.rows.to_a.index{ |row| row.td(:css => "td[bgcolor=yellow]").present? }
offset = 3
row = browser.table.row(:index, starting_row_index + offset)
puts row.text
# => ETS36401 ...

#Output the first column text of each row after the row containing a cell with yellow background colour
starting_row_index = browser.table.rows.to_a.index{ |row| row.td(:css => "td[bgcolor=yellow]").present? }
(starting_row_index + 1).upto(browser.table.rows.length - 1){ |x| puts browser.table[x][0].text }
# => CAT03, CAT08, ..., INTEGRA10, INTEGRA11
```

Let me know if that helps or if you have a specific example you want.

Comment: Thank you so much! Thats exactly what I was trying to do, especially the last example!